# Converting uint_32_t to network-byte-order results in shorter bit length than expected

Tags: c

I'm trying to convert an `uint_64_t` to network-byte-order, in order to do so, I'm splitting the `uint_64_t` into two `uint_32_t` in order to use `htonl`, since it can only be used with `uint_32_t`. I'm splitting it in the following manner:

```
uint32_t partA = (uint32_t) (x);
uint32_t partB = (uint32_t) (x >> 32);
```

when I enter for example `x=1`, I correctly get `partA=1`, `partB=0`, which makes perfect sense:

1 -> `[00000000000000000000000000000000][00000000000000000000000000000001]`

Now, I decided to apply ntohl to each individual part like so:

```
uint32_t partA = htonl((uint32_t) (x));
uint32_t partB = htonl((uint32_t) (x >> 32)));
```

I would expect that partA should contain the bits the other way around (big endian), so it should hold the value `10000000000000000000000000000000` (32b), but instead, the value is `1000000000000000000000000` (25b), 7b shorter than it should be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Byte** order is applied to bytes, not bits.

`1` is expressed in bytes `0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00` (little-endian) or `0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01` (big-endian).

Expressed in bits, they are `00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000` and `00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001`.

The former `00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000` has 7 trailing zeros, so removing these zeros results in 7 bits shorter result.